# How do I guide Dampe around?

Tags: zelda-majoras-mask-3d

Dampe is under one of the gravestones in Ikana Graveyard.  He asks me to guide him around, but he follows me for a second and then wanders off to some seemingly random direction.

How do I guide him to the various dirt spots he needs to dig up?

Comment: Are you coming close to Poe's? The wiki suggests this happens when you come close to a Poe.

Comment: @Ben I didn't see any Poes.  I suppose they could have been invisible... however, Dampe kept complaining about me going too fast when he went the wrong way.  Maybe I should wait until I complete Great Bay and try to do it again.

Comment: He follows Talt, so try locking on to him and backing up slowly. If you put Talt away he has no light to follow and gets lost.

Comment: @AdamP You really should make that an answer.

Comment: @Powerlord Done. I didn't originally because the comment was just based on personal experience. I was sure someone with more knowledge of the actual mechanics would come around and really answer the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

He follows Tatl, so try locking onto him and backing up slowly. If you put Tatl away he has no light to follow and gets lost.

I have been told that Poes are no longer in this puzzle for the 3DS version, however I leave the following here in case someone brushes off their old N64 and has this question.

He will also seem to get lost when he gets distracted by the light of a poe. This is fixed by removing the distraction.

Comment: As far as I can tell, the 3DS version doesn't seem to have Poes under the grave... except the mini-boss that appears once Dampe digs up the 3 blue flame pillar things.

Comment: That's good to know. I have not actually gotten to this point in the 3DS version yet so my comment (and then answer) was based purely off 14 year old memories.

Comment: Well, technically I came to this area early... was trying to complete as much of the Bomber's Notebook before tackling Great Bay temple.  To the point where the Bombers stopped offering me rumors and I already have all the bottles in the game.

Comment: "distracted by the light of a poe...fixed by removing the distraction" +1 for delivery.